# Apple Script - How to click menu items inside menu of a button?

Tags: applescript

[image]

Please find the screenshot above for the element path. Apple script event throws an error while clicking *click menu item "X" of menu 1 of button 3 of window "Movie Recording"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `click` the button, wait a bit and then `pick` the menu item

```
activate application "QuickTime Player"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "QuickTime Player"
        tell window "Movie Recording"
            click button 3
            delay 0.2
            pick menu item "Maximum" of menu 1 of button 3
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```